# Prevent button flatstyle from changing color behavior

Tags: c#

I'm creating a form app. I'm willing to create a different theme (dark) so I made some tests for the buttons and found out it would be good to change the flatstyle to popup for the dark theme.

The dark theme is ok. The problem is if the button is disabled, when I change it back to standard, the button looks different than it normally should. It should be dark-ish grey with greyed out text, instead it becomes "clear" with a more visible text. Since I have MANY buttons to manage, I'm willing and trying to use some basic instructions and assignments.

Basically, I tried changing the backcolor as it should (225, 225, 225, not Control, otherwise it still becomes clear taking the Form backcolor) and this slightly works, meaning this involves only the border of the button and the major part has instead a brighter color than it should.
Do you have an idea how I could get around this easily? In the image you can see 2 buttons as they should be and the one behaving as it shouldn't. Just to make it clear, I have about 20-30 buttons to handle, so a simple solution would be nice.

The code I use is

```
        private void lighttheme()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < pulsantisvuota.Count; i++)
            {
                pulsantisvuota[i].BackColor = Color.FromArgb(225, 225, 225);
                pulsantisvuota[i].FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Standard;
            }
        }
        private void darktheme()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < pulsantisvuota.Count; i++)
            {
                pulsantisvuota[i].BackColor = Color.FromArgb(80, 80, 80);
                pulsantisvuota[i].FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Popup;
            }
        }
```

[image: Example image]

Comment: The middle button is enabled and the other two are disabled? I don't get it. Maybe a [mre] would be nice after all.

Comment: I don't know how I could create a reproducible demo...yes, it is, it is disabled.

Comment: Enabled buttons look different than disabled buttons. That's my expectation as a user.

Comment: No, maybe you don't get it. The button is disabled. All 3 are disabled in the image. The second one is the button I changed with the properties. When I revert it back to "normal" colors and flatstyle, it looks different than the others and I don't know how to prevent or fix this...

Comment: "I don't know how I could create a reproducible demo" - create a copy of your code and reduce the buttons to those 2 which are needed to demo the different. Remove all other code. Whenever there's user input needed, hard code it instead.

Comment: i edited the post with at the bottom the code i use to change the buttons properties

Answer (score 1):

I solved this changing slightly the code for lighttheme() as follows:

```
private void lighttheme()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < pulsantisvuota.Count; i++)
            {
                pulsantisvuota[i].BackColor = DefaultBackColor;
                pulsantisvuota[i].UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
                pulsantisvuota[i].FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Standard;
            }
        }
```